# 8.1 stopped working after content node deletion. NullReferenceException, Powershell Pipeline Issue?

Tags: powershell-extensions, login

8.1 won't let us log back in. While attempting to delete a node with ~16k sub-items we couldn't tell whether 8.1 was frozen or still trying to delete. We restarted site/app pool & now can't log in. We get to the login screen but get a server error after the login. Any help/recs are appreciated!

```
 Stack trace:
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Core.Extensions.ItemExtensions.InheritsFrom(Item item, ID templateID) +89
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Core.Extensions.ItemExtensions.IsPowerShellModule(Item item) +105
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Core.Modules.ModuleManager.EnumerateLibraries(Item library, List`1 dbModules) +217
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Core.Modules.ModuleManager.GetDbModules(String database) +305
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Core.Modules.ModuleManager.get_Modules() +245
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Core.Modules.ModuleManager.GetFeatureRoots(String featureName) +119
   Cognifide.PowerShell.Integrations.Pipelines.PipelineProcessor`1.Process(TPipelineArgs args) +134
```

Comment: What type of items were you deleting i.e. Content, Layouts, System, Templates, etc.?

Comment: Whenever I have severe issues like this, I start by disabling patch config files, one by one, and try to login after each. There might be a config file that is looking for one of those items that was deleted and is causing this error.

Comment: Are you able to login after disabling `Cognifide.PowerShell.config`? Also, please include the version of SPE and a sample script as to what you are running.

Comment: - Trying to delete Content items

Comment: Was using the built in Delete button under Operations section of Toolbar ribbon

Comment: We are running SPE 4.3 for Sitecore 8

Comment: Michael,  disabled Cognifide.PowerShell.config and yes am now able to log in

Comment: Just re-installed SPE 4.3. I am now able to login (Cognifide.PowerShell.config is no longer disabled) and it appears 'everything' is functional once again.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer Based on Comment Thread

Based on your Stack Trace, it appears that while some content items were deleted, potentially, other items needed for the successful operation of the sitecore Powershell Extension module were also removed inadvertently.

Disabling the module, should make the error go away.  If that is the case, you might try reinstalling the Powershell Module to see if any items that it needs were accidently removed.

### Bulk Deleting of Items

Anytime I am in the process of deleting a bulk sum of items like this, I always make an effort to take a backup of the master and/or web database so that in the event of an issue like this, I can restore to a functional database, and reassess what I'm asking Sitecore to delete. In this case, it seems that it was just the removal of something that Powershell is expecting. However, in your mind, if you are *just removing content items* it's clear to me that something else was deleted.  That begs the question, what else might have been deleted.

**Rule of Thumb:** Always have backups handy. =)